# android: Activity.startActivityForResult() or ActivityGroup?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the following situation:

1. activity A -> resultA
2. activity B -> resultB
3. activity C -> resultC

and I need all the results (A, B & C) to build the final out put?

What's the better way:

```
AA extends Activity  {

startActivityForResult(A);
startActivityForResult(A);
startActivityForResult(A);

}
```

or to make AA subtype of ActivityGroup?

Activities A, B and C do not require to be visible (foreground) at the same time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, none of the above.

Popping out of one activity into another briefly via `startActivityForResult()` is fine...once. It gets cumbersome for users and developers alike when there are several.

Consider recasting your UI as a wizard, perhaps driven by a `ViewFlipper`, so you can keep all of this in a single activity. It also provides the user with a recognized pattern for going back and forth within the chain of steps leading to them providing all of the information you need.

Comment: Great! Thanks - I hoped that there is some utility for building wizard! This is exactly what I needed!